# How to improve the runtime of this simple data cleaning code?

Tags: python, numpy, data-cleaning

I am pre-processing a large dataframe for analysis.
Basically, I am trying to find the largest number or close to largest number ('close' is defined as more than `0.9*largest number`) in a column and label it with `1` while keep the other positions as `0`,
i.e. if a columns contains `[25, 3, 5, 24, 0]` it should be converted into `[1,0,0,1,0]`. Somehow the code I've written is taking forever to run.

I have written a simple list comprehension to clean the data column by column. The code took less than 1 second to run for the first 2,000 columns. However, it became very slow and took more than half an hour when I increase the number of columns to 10,000. Eventually I want to run this code on a 5-million-row dataset, is there something wrong that I should be changing to make it more efficient?

```
tic = time.time()

for col in temp_dataset_1.iloc[:,:10000]:
    temp_dataset_1[col] = [1 if i >= i.max()*.9 else 0 for i in temp_dataset_1[col]]

toc = time.time() - tic
print('Calculating 10,000 out of 5,810,172 rows took %d seconds' %toc)
#temp_dataset_1.iloc[:,:10000].head(n=5)
```

My data structure knowledge is limited, is there something obvious that I am missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it a try to this approach using numpy:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create fake data (this should take around 9s)
tic = time.time()
value2 = []
for x in range(10000):
    value1 = []
    for y in range(10000):
        value1.append(x)
    value2.append(value1)

print(time.time() - tic)
tic = time.time()
temp_dataset_1 = pd.DataFrame(value2)


for col in temp_dataset_1.iloc[:,:10]:
    max_value = max(temp_dataset_1[col])
    a = np.array(temp_dataset_1[col].values.tolist())
    temp_dataset_1[col] = np.where(a >= max_value*.9, 1, 0).tolist()

print(temp_dataset_1.shape)
toc = time.time() - tic
print('Calculating 10,000 out of 5,810,172 rows took %d seconds' %toc)
```

For a 10K x 10K matrix the time was 19 seconds:

```
Calculating 10,000 out of 5,810,172 rows took 19 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks bleand! Tried the numpy approach and was able to calculate for the entire dataset in about half an hour. Really helpful advice!

Comment: Awesome news. I don't think you can reduce that time much more, you have a lot of data! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Find the max value of the column before the list comprehension step and iterate only through the column names.

```
import pandas as pd
temp_dataset_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[25,3,5,25,0,1,2], 'B':[20, 21, 19, 18,17,25,26]})
for col in list(temp_dataset_1):
    compare_val = temp_dataset_1[col].max()*.9
    temp_dataset_1[col] = [1 if i >= compare_val else 0 for i in temp_dataset_1[col]]
```

original dataframe :

```
   A   B
0  25  20
1   3  21
2   5  19
3  25  18
4   0  17
5   1  25
6   2  26
```

after changing values:

```
   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  1  0
4  0  0
5  0  1
6  0  1
```

you can further increase the speed by using vectorization with numpy,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def loop(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        _max = df[col].max()*0.9
        df[col] = np.where(df[col]>= _max,1,0)

def calc_(df_col):
    _max = df_col.max()*0.9
    return np.where(df_col>= _max,1,0)
def numpy_vectorise(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = calc_(df[col].values)
```

timings for `loop` and `numpy_vectorise` are as below

```
# dataframe of size 100,000 x 100
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(1000, (100000,100),replace=True))
%timeit loop(df)
%timeit numpy_vectorise(df)
```

**loop**            :    `616ms ± 8.5ms per loop(mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs,1 loop each)`
**numpy_vectorise** : `410ms ± 6.37ms per loop(mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs,1 loop each)`

you can increase speed unto **1.5x** using numpy vectorization

Comment: Thanks for the input Shijith. I tried your recommendations, unfortunately, this change did not improve my code performance much. Fyi, the for-loop is iterating through the column names only even without the list() function. Thanks anws.